# VsCode/Python in console: file not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my workingdirectory I have many folders with a python script modifying data in the same folder.
When running Python in VsCode I need to give a relative path from the working directory into the folder. For example using os.getcwd(), test.py is in D:\Workingdirectory\Folder1: VsCode says, D:\Workingdirectory. Running it in console: D:\Workingdirectory\Folder1.
Direct path is not an option.
How fo i fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by vscode using workspace as root floder.

This will lead to a problem. When you use the `os.getcwd()` method in the deep directory of the workspace, you will still get the workspace directory.

You can open your settings and search **Python > Terminal: Execute In File Dir** then check it.

[image]

You can also use debug mode and add the following to your **launch.json**:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your external terminal works normally, you can also use it as default in vscode by changing the option [Terminal: Explorer Kind] to external.
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOS3F.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).